# Fontawesome refused to load Django project to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-templates

I bought a template that i'm trying to adapt to my Django project. When I run it locally, it run correctly and now I did all the Django-Heroku setup correctly and now  tried to push the project to Heroku it failed.
I did : git push heroku master

result :
[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUYZZ.png)
Then run python manage.py collectstatic
result:
[first screensho2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzlO8.png)

[first screensho3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed0pU.png)

I tried some search and people who got the same issue and fix, said they replace some paths in the CSS file. if it is correctly where and how to do that. Please I'm novice in CSS and want a detail explanation. My assets folder as (ajax, css, img, js, scss and vendor) files. the project is in src and static files path is :
C:\Users\Dell User\Desktop\virtual\GrandBuzz\src\home\static 
full path to fontawesome-for-theme.css is :
C:\Users\Dell User\Desktop\virtual\GrandBuzz\src\home\static\home\assets\vendor\fontawesome-free\css\fontawesome-for-theme.css

Comment: Did you try running collectstatic command on your computer before pushing?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing this from a windows machine, Can you tell the full path of the fontawesome-for-theme.css file in your project or dir structure of your project.

There might be a problem in the way you are referring the file. Try to use the concept of './' or '../' before the file path Or try giving the full file path wherever possible (which is not the idle way).

Comment: This is the full path : C:\Users\Dell User\Desktop\virtual\GrandBuzz\src\home\static\home\assets\vendor\fontawesome-free\css\fontawesome-for-theme.css

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because of relative import inside `fontawesome-for-them.css` as it references to the file `../webfonts/fa-brand-400.eot` (and more).

A quick solution would be adding the `webfonts` folder to your static files.